# "Only one root element is allowed" but I only have one?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to make a website for a friend, and my experience is definitely not XML/XSLT heavy.

I have a very simple stored procedure which generates XML:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[setXMLData]
as

SELECT
    (SELECT title as '@Title',
       linkpath as '@Linkpath',
       displayOrder as '@displayOrder' FROM dbo.tblSiteMenuSections order by displayorder asc FOR XML PATH('SiteMenu'), TYPE) AS 'MENU',
    (SELECT imgPath as '@imgPath',
       displayOrder as '@displayOrder' FROM dbo.tblBannerSlides order by displayorder asc FOR XML PATH('SlideShow'), TYPE) AS 'SLIDES'
FOR XML PATH('Site')
```

Which returns this XML:

```
<Site>
  <MENU>
    <SiteMenu Title="Edo" Linkpath="/default.aspx" displayOrder="0" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Infomation" Linkpath="/information.aspx" displayOrder="1" />
    <SiteMenu Title="News" Linkpath="/news.aspx" displayOrder="2" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Menu" Linkpath="/menu.aspx" displayOrder="3" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Gallery" Linkpath="/gallery.aspx" displayOrder="4" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Contact" Linkpath="/contact.aspx" displayOrder="5" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Catering" Linkpath="/catering.aspx" displayOrder="6" />
  </MENU>
  <SLIDES>
    <SlideShow imgPath="/20160806_182949.jpg" displayOrder="1" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/20160901_193700.jpg" displayOrder="2" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/14202562_319650221718312_9092982335636542049_n.jpg" displayOrder="3" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/14237745_319766348373366_7639011255502415884_n.jpg" displayOrder="4" />
  </SLIDES>
</Site>
```

I'm trying to get this XML to load in chrome and to style some basic HTML but it only loads a blank page. I'm using the following code to do so, which runs on page load.

```
private void buildXML()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("server=[REDACTED]; database= [TOTALLY NOT GOVERNMENT SECRETS; persist security info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.setXMLData", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        string xmlPrefix = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"/XSLT/Templates.xslt\"?>";
        xRead = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        xRead.Read();
        xmlPrefix += Environment.NewLine + xRead.ReadOuterXml();
        pXml.LoadXml(xmlPrefix);
        Response.Write(pXml.OuterXml);
    }
```

However when I try to load the page, chrome only shows a blank page (with the xml nodes all nested inside other in the element inspector... like those little russian dolls) and IE shows the "only one root element" error.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but several hours of trawling other questions and googling the answer haven't helped.

**EDIT**

This is the `xslt` stylesheet I'm using, it has some extra content in it not yet being supplied by SQL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head runat="server">
        <title>[Site Title]</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" href="~/Assets/styles.css" />
        <script src="/Assets/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/scripts.js"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700" rel="stylesheet"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="form1" class="main-page" runat="server">
          <xsl:call-template name="main-slideshow"/>
          <div id="logo">
            <img class="logo_main" src="Images/main_logo.png" />
          </div>
          <div id="suppliers">
            <div class="supplier-images">
              <img class="supplier" src="Images/1398770711.png" />
              <label class="supplier-label">[name]</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <xsl:call-template name="menu-setup"/>
          <div>
            <button id="btnBooking" class="button-booking">Reservation</button>
          </div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close">x</span>
              <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
            </div>

          </div>

          </div>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="main-slideshow">
    <div>
      <xsl:variable name="slideCount" select="count(//Slideshow)" />
      <div id="CSS3Slideshow {$slideCount}">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ROOT/SLIDES/Slideshow">
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <img class="img{$pos}" src="@imgPath"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="CSS3Slideshow">
                <img class="img" src="Images/20160806_182949.jpg" />
                <img class="img2" src="Images/20160901_193700.jpg" />
                <img class="img3" src="Images/14202562_319650221718312_9092982335636542049_n.jpg" />
                <img class="img4" src="Images/14237745_319766348373366_7639011255502415884_n.jpg"/>
            </div>-->
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="menu-setup">
    <div id="menu-bar">
      <ol class="menu-list">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ROOT/MENU/SiteMenu">
          <xsl:variable name="linkPath" select="@LinkPath"/>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=1">
              <a href="{$linkPath}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
              </a>
              <li class="menu-item-separator-Line">|</li>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <li class="menu-item-separator-icon">&#9654;</li>
              <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="{$linkPath}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
                </a>
              </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </ol>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit 2**
If I inspect the page in chrome I get this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!--?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/XSLT/Templates.xslt"?-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
    <body>
        <site>
           <menu>
               <sitemenu title="Edo" linkpath="/default.aspx" displayorder="0">
<sitemenu title="Infomation" linkpath="/information.aspx" displayorder="1"><sitemenu title="News" linkpath="/news.aspx" displayorder="2">
<sitemenu title="Menu" linkpath="/menu.aspx" displayorder="3">
<sitemenu title="Gallery" linkpath="/gallery.aspx" displayorder="4">
<sitemenu title="Contact" linkpath="/contact.aspx" displayorder="5">
<sitemenu title="Catering" linkpath="/catering.aspx" displayorder="6"></sitemenu>
</sitemenu>
</sitemenu>
</sitemenu>
</sitemenu>
</sitemenu>
</sitemenu>
</menu>
<slides>
<slideshow imgpath="/20160806_182949.jpg" displayorder="1">
<slideshow imgpath="/20160901_193700.jpg" displayorder="2">
<slideshow imgpath="/14202562_319650221718312_9092982335636542049_n.jpg" displayorder="3">
<slideshow imgpath="/14237745_319766348373366_7639011255502415884_n.jpg" displayorder="4">
</slideshow>
</slideshow>
</slideshow>
</slideshow>
</slides>
</site>
```

But in IE I get this

```
<xml:stylesheet></xml:stylesheet>
<Site>
  <MENU>
    <SiteMenu Title="Edo" Linkpath="/default.aspx" displayOrder="0" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Infomation" Linkpath="/information.aspx" displayOrder="1" />
    <SiteMenu Title="News" Linkpath="/news.aspx" displayOrder="2" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Menu" Linkpath="/menu.aspx" displayOrder="3" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Gallery" Linkpath="/gallery.aspx" displayOrder="4" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Contact" Linkpath="/contact.aspx" displayOrder="5" />
    <SiteMenu Title="Catering" Linkpath="/catering.aspx" displayOrder="6" />
  </MENU>
  <SLIDES>
    <SlideShow imgPath="/20160806_182949.jpg" displayOrder="1" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/20160901_193700.jpg" displayOrder="2" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/14202562_319650221718312_9092982335636542049_n.jpg" displayOrder="3" />
    <SlideShow imgPath="/14237745_319766348373366_7639011255502415884_n.jpg" displayOrder="4" />
  </SLIDES>
</Site>
```

And a console error that still says "Only one root element is allowed" when it's pretty clear that `<site` is the only root element.

**Edit 3**

My view in Chrome:

[image: blank page in chrome]

Comment: Please show us your stylesheet. -- Re Chrome, do a search for `[xslt]+chrome`

Comment: Stylesheet added in edit.

Comment: Is that website online so that we can see/test with a browser how the response looks? On the other hand, as you use server-side programming (C#?), I wonder why you do not simply perform the XSLT on the server and send the resulting HTML to the client. As you currently send XML, does the server side code make sure to send the right `Content-Type: application/xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet has an extra `</div>` close tag on line 41.

Once you fix that, a valid HTML is produced (although I don't see anything rendered to the screen, unless I remove the two `script` links).

Comment: I fixed the `</div>` and removed the script links and I still get nothing. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: What do you mean by "get nothing"? As I said, the result of your XSL transformation is an HTML document. You need to know what the HTML document should look like before you try to produce it using XSLT. Then test if the transformation produces the wanted document - and don't use a browser to perform this test.

Comment: There is nothing rendered to screen, just the xml nodes in the dev tools window. I've added a screenshot. Let's assume I'm an idiot, if I'm not supposed to test the view by looking in a browser, what should I use?

Comment: If you don't have a development environment, you could use an online test tool such as http://xsltransform.net/ (when it's not down, as it often is, sadly).

Comment: I'm using VS Studio 2013 (Community free version), and it's not showing me any errors when I try to debug the site. Is there a tool/option I can use in VS?

Comment: We are going in a circle. If you save the result of your XSL transformation as an HTML document and load it in a browser, nothing is displayed. I already said this in my answer above. The problem is not with **how** you do the XSL transformation, but **what** do you want the result to be. Of this we know nothing - and the topic of such question would be HTML, not XSLT.  -- I am afraid I know nothing about VS Studio.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help.